# ReactJS: read property 'maps' of undefined if i click back the browser

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I'm just new in ReactJS,

**Module:**

I have module, create a google map by https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps And once users click the direction button it will automatically show the marker position of that. **Note:** Every **ID's** has different position and places.

**Problem and Scenario:**

Scenario 1.
[image: First Scenario]

That is the direction button. If i click that button it will redirect the store_directory to find-store-location/ID

[image: Scenario]

Take a look the marker successfully change the position of marker. which is correct.

**Scenario having problem:**
[image: Scenario 2]

If i try to **find again another location or different ID of place** and try to click back the browser
my browser give white screen only and the error

> defaultCenter: new google.maps.LatLng(props.lat, props.lng)

[image: Problem]

**My Codes:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link , Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps";
const { MarkerClusterer } = require("react-google-maps/lib/components/addons/MarkerClusterer");
const { compose, withProps, withHandlers, lifecycle} = require("recompose");

import axios from 'axios';
import SearchInput, {createFilter} from 'react-search-input';
const KEYS_TO_FILTERS = ['city', 'branch_name', 'store_address'];

const google = window.google
const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=AIzaSyDWCz4V5r29GxcGZKNtFzE9v4gOSnKVMYA",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,

  }),
  withHandlers({
    onMarkerClustererClick: () => (markerClusterer) => {
      const clickedMarkers = markerClusterer.getMarkers()
      console.log(`Current clicked markers length: ${clickedMarkers.length}`)
      console.log(clickedMarkers)
    },
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props =>

<GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={8}
    defaultCenter={new google.maps.LatLng(props.lat, props.lng)}

>

    {props.markers.map(marker => (

        <Marker
            key={marker.id}
            position={{ lat: parseFloat(marker.store_lat), lng: parseFloat(marker.store_long) }}
        />

    ))}

</GoogleMap>
);

export default class FindStore extends Component {


      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          text:'',
          city:'',
          store_details:[],
          searchTerm: '',
          lat_value:'',
          lng_value:'',
          markers: [],
          lat:this.props.lat,
          lng:this.props.lng
        }

        this.searchUpdated = this.searchUpdated.bind(this)
      }


      componentDidMount() {

        const id = this.props.match.params.id;
        axios.get('/api/find_store_location/' + id).then(response => {
            this.setState({
                markers: response.data,
                lat_value:response.data[0].store_lat,
                lng_value:response.data[0].store_long,
            })

        }).catch(error => console.log(error));

        axios.get('/api/store_details').then(response => {
            this.setState({

              store_details:response.data

            })
           }).catch(error => console.log(error.response));
      }

      //store details oveflow leftside
    render() {

      const filteredEmails = this.state.store_details.filter(createFilter(this.state.searchTerm, KEYS_TO_FILTERS))
      return (


        <div>

          <div className="header">
              <div className="jumbotron">
                  <h1>Store Directory</h1>
              </div>
          </div>
          <br/><br/><br/>

          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">

              <div className="col-md-7">

                 <MyMapComponent 
                    markers={this.state.markers}  
                    lat={this.state.lat_value}
                    lng={this.state.lng_value}
                 />
              </div>

              <div className="col-md-5">
                <form method="get" onSubmit={this.SubmitFilterStore}>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="exampleSelect1">Select City</label>
                    <select value={this.state.city} className="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
                      <option readOnly={true} selected={true} >Choose City</option>
                      <option value="Winnipeg">Winnipeg</option>
                      <option value="Edmonton">Edmonton</option>
                      <option value="Calgary">Calgary</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div className="input-group mb-3" id="text_search">

                    <SearchInput className="search-input" onChange={this.searchUpdated} />

                    <div style={{overflowY:'scroll', height:'500px'}}>
                      {filteredEmails.map(store => {

                        if(store.image == "")
                        {
                          return (
                            <div className="store" key={store.id}>
                              <div className="card" style={{width: '18rem' }}>
                                  <div className="container">
                                  <br/>
                                    <p>No Store Image Uploaded</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div className="card-body">
                                     <div id="store-description">
                                     <label>{store.branch_name}</label><br/> 
                                      <label>{store.store_type}</label><br/> 
                                      <label>{store.store_contactnumber}</label><br/> 
                                      <label>{store.store_businesshour}</label>
                                      <br/><br/>
                                      <a href={'/find-store-location/'+store.id}>Direction <i className="fas fa-directions fa-2x"></i></a>
                                     </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>      
                                <br/>    
                            </div>
                          )
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          return (
                            <div className="store" key={store.id}>
                              <div className="card" style={{width: '18rem' }}>
                                  <div className="container">
                                  <br/>
                                  <img src={"/storage/"+store.image}
                                    height="120" 
                                  className="img-responsive"></img>

                                  </div>
                                  <div className="card-body">
                                      <div id="store-description">
                                        <label>{store.branch_name}</label><br/> 
                                        <label>{store.store_type}</label><br/> 
                                        <label>{store.store_contactnumber}</label><br/> 
                                        <label>{store.store_businesshour}</label>
                                        <br/><br/>
                                        <a href={'/find-store-location/'+store.id}>Direction <i className="fas fa-directions fa-2x"></i></a>
                                      </div>

                                  </div>
                                </div>      
                                <br/>    
                            </div>
                          )
                        }

                    })}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>  
              </div>   
            </div>


          </div>
        </div>


      )
    }

    searchUpdated (term) {
      this.setState({searchTerm: term})
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add your error msg to observe. Alternately, you can use  defaultCenter={{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng }} syntax as in the docs.

Comment: @XPD i already add the error msg , read my message their.. yes I tried defaultCenter already.

Comment: Error you have added is in the sources pane. Add the error displayed in console tab since it has more insights. If you tried the other way, then it solved the issue?

Comment: the other way is not solved for me..

Comment: @DevGe, where in the documentation did you receive guidance to write the line of code `defaultCenter={new google.maps.LatLng(props.lat, props.lng)}`?

Comment: @Daniel hi daniel, sorry for delay reply to you.. i'm off ago.. for your question. I just copy that logic answer to the other..

Comment: @DevGe, I asked because I do not see your implementation in the docs as show here: https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#installation